# Kotlin: variable in Object class can't use safe call(?.)

Tags: kotlin, null

I have kotlin code as follows:

```
object Manager {
@kotlin.jvm.JvmField
var responseCallback: ResponseCallback?=null;}

interface ResponseCallback {
fun onEnrollmentFailed( error:Int,  msg:String)}
```

When I call Manager in java class as follows:

```
Manager.responseCallback?.onEnrollmentFailed(1," ");
```

There is an error in above code.

Because "responseCallback" could be null, so I have to do safe call (?.)check here.

What is the reason I can't call safe call?

Comment: Do you mean that you try to do a safe call from a Java file? In Java there is no safe call. You can do a manual check to see if responseCallback is null before calling `onEnrollmentFailed`.

Comment: Oh, I forget it. There is no safe call in java

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the snippet below is Java one. Unfortunately, Java syntax doesn't support null-safe calls, but you can check the value manually:

```java
var callback = Manager.responseCallback;
if (callback != null) callback.onEnrollmentFailed(1, " ");
```